# 3次元配列でitertoolsを用いて組み合わせを求めたい

Tags: python

3次元配列でitertoolsを用いて組み合わせを求めようと考えています。
li1[i]のところから１通りずつ選ぶ総組み合わせを求めたいです。

```
li1=[[[0, 2],[0,1,2]], 
     [[3]], 
     [[7, 9], [7,8,9],[7,6,9]], 
     [[11]], 
     [[12, 10, 20], [12, 14, 18, 20]]]
```

例えばli1[i]の先頭を組み合わせた場合はli1[0][0]→li1[1][0]→li1[2][0]→li1[3][0]li1[4][0]で[0,2,3,7,9,11,12,10,20]となります。

```
result=[[0,2,3,7,9,11,12,10,20],[0,2,3,7,9,11,12,14,18,20],
        [0,2,3,7, 8, 9,11,12,10,20],[0,2,3,7, 8, 9,11,12,14,18,20],
        [0,2,3,7,6,9,11,12,10,20],[0,2,3,7,6,9,11,12,14,18,20],
        [0,1,2,3,7,9,11,12,10,20],[0,1,2,3,7,9,11,12,14,18,20],
        [0,1,2,3,7,8,9,11,12,10,20],[0,1,2,3,7,8,9,11,12,14,18,20],
        [0,1,2,3,7,6,9,11,12,10,20],[0,1,2,3,7,6,9,11,12,14,18,20]]
```

itertoolsを用いない方法でも構いません。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [sum(list(l), []) for l in apply(itertools.product, li1)]
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。参考にさせて頂きます。